# XSLT 2.0: Group-By and Sum Issue

Tags: xslt, group-by, xslt-2.0

**Here is my source XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <empID>12354</empID>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>108</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Bonus</Type>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>550</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>100</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Bonus</Type>
            <Amount>200</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>120</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-11-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>120</Amount>
        </Cost>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <empID>4567</empID>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>90</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Bonus</Type>
            <Amount>10</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>120</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Expense</Type>
            <Amount>1297</Amount>
        </Cost>
        <Cost>
            <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
            <Type>Bonus</Type>
            <Amount>312</Amount>
        </Cost>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

**Expected output**

- Group the record based on `<empID>` and `<Date>`
- Create as many `Worker` nodes as equal to unique `<Date>`values so I have three unique `<Date>` values under 1st `<Worker>` node that has `<empID>` value as `12354`. My expected output XML needs to contain three `<Worker>` nodes for `<empID>` `12354` because there are three unique  values such as
- 2023-10-06-07:00
- 2023-10-10-07:00
- 2023-10-11-07:00

and two `<Worker>` nodes for `<empID>` `4567` because there are two unique  values such as

- 2023-10-06-07:00
- 2023-10-10-07:00
- Sum the amount for `Type` of `Expense` for a unique `<Date>`
- Sum the amount for `Type` of `Bonus` for a unique `<Date>`

**Expected Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>658.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>200.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>220.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>200.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-11-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount/>
        <BonusAmount>120.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>210.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>10.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
    <Worker>
        <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
        <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
        <ExpenseAmount>1297.00</ExpenseAmount>
        <BonusAmount>312.00</BonusAmount>
    </Worker>
</Workers>
```

**Here is my XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Workers">
        <Workers>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker" group-by="empID">
                <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Cost/Date">
                    <Worker>
                        <UniqueID>
                            <xsl:value-of select="empID"/>
                        </UniqueID>
                        <Date>
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                        </Date>
                        <ExpenseAmount>
                            <xsl:value-of
                                select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Cost[Type = 'Expense']/Amount), '#.00')"/>
                        </ExpenseAmount>
                        <BonusAmount>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Cost[Type = 'Bonus']/Amount), '#.00')"/>
                        </BonusAmount>
                    </Worker>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Workers>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workers>
   <Worker>
      <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
      <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
      <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
      <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
   </Worker>
   <Worker>
      <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
      <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
      <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
      <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
   </Worker>
   <Worker>
      <UniqueID>12354</UniqueID>
      <Date>2023-10-11-07:00</Date>
      <ExpenseAmount>998.00</ExpenseAmount>
      <BonusAmount>400.00</BonusAmount>
   </Worker>
   <Worker>
      <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
      <Date>2023-10-06-07:00</Date>
      <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
      <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
   </Worker>
   <Worker>
      <UniqueID>4567</UniqueID>
      <Date>2023-10-10-07:00</Date>
      <ExpenseAmount>1507.00</ExpenseAmount>
      <BonusAmount>322.00</BonusAmount>
   </Worker>
</Workers>
```

**Issue**

`ExpenseAmount` and `BonusAmount` are incorrect

Could anyone help me figure out what I should be doing to get the sum value as provided in the expected output?

Comment: Can the input XML really contain more than one `Worker` element with same `empID`? It seems you only need to group the `Cost` elements within each `Worker`. In any case, the problem with your current attempt is that your secondary grouping groups `Worker` elements again, instead of `Cost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you only need to do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Workers">
    <Workers>
        <xsl:for-each select="Worker">
            <xsl:variable name="empID" select="empID" />
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Cost" group-by="Date">
                <Worker>
                    <UniqueID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$empID"/>
                    </UniqueID>
                    <Date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </Date>
                    <ExpenseAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()[Type = 'Expense']/Amount), '0.00')"/>
                    </ExpenseAmount>
                    <BonusAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()[Type = 'Bonus']/Amount), '0.00')"/>
                    </BonusAmount>
                </Worker>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Workers>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To do it the way you started it would need to be:

```
<xsl:template match="Workers">
    <Workers>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="Worker" group-by="empID">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/Cost" group-by="Date">
                <Worker>
                    <UniqueID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../empID"/>
                    </UniqueID>
                    <Date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </Date>
                    <ExpenseAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()[Type = 'Expense']/Amount), '#.00')"/>
                    </ExpenseAmount>
                    <BonusAmount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()[Type = 'Bonus']/Amount), '#.00')"/>
                    </BonusAmount>
                </Worker>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Workers>
</xsl:template>
```